# Automatic syntax highlighting for [fortran]

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

I had assumed from [Syntax highlighting for Fortran?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315269/syntax-highlighting-for-fortran) on MSO and [Please deploy Fortran syntax highlighting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358865/please-deploy-fortran-syntax-highlighting) on MSE that Fortran syntax highlighting was not available on Stack Overfow.

But [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54241608/question-about-procedure-pointer-as-a-class-member) on SO has lovely Fortran syntax highlighting, using

```
<!-- language: lang-fortran -->
```

Would it be possible to roll out this syntax highlighting as default to all questions with the [fortran] tag?

Comment: Related (has the list of supported languages): *[What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109)*

Comment: It looks like Fortran is in the [Supported Languages list](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/main/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md) at highlight.js and has been for more than a year. I'm confused as to where that leaves things in the [how to request a new language FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work).

Comment: Ok, I think I understand now. The MSE post *is* where things are at in the process outlined in the FAQ, and the nearly-a-year delay is because the powers that be are understandably very busy :) I've closed my question as a dupe, because I don't think it adds anything new.

Comment: The linked Fortran question has now been deleted (RemoveAbandonedQuestions).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really that lovely.

`lang-fortran` doesn't exist, so it falls back to the "default" syntax highlighting, which is what you were seeing. You're now seeing exactly that same thing when I set it to `lang-default`.  What you read about Fortran not being supported by Stack Overflow's syntax highlighting engine is correct. Although highlight.js supports it, Stack Overflow does not import it, so it doesn't work here.

I *can* set the syntax highlighting hint for the [fortran](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fortran) tag to "default", which will create the same effect. But, honestly… The default best-guess syntax highlighting is pretty lame. I guess it at least gives the code some splotches of color, which is kinda nice, but it doesn't actually understand the syntax of the code, and so the syntax highlighting is not really very useful. I consider it to be more distracting than anything.

I'll let the community weigh in on whether they think this is a good idea.

Comment: As a user who glances at [tag:fortran], I'm going to interpret "not really that lovely" as "awful, distracting, and painfully wrong at times".